how to draw text into a canvas?
What happens

What i tried

function draw() {
    canvas.width = canvaWidth;
    canvas.height = canvaHeight;
    ctx.fillStyle("blue")
    ctx.font("48px serif");
    ctx.fillText("test", 10, 10);
}

draw();


Return this

What should happen
Should have text in it

The duplicate explains exactly how you should approach this. If your code isn't working, check the console for errors, then compare to the example in the duplicate.
